Springboot oauth2 auth server with native (android) social (google) login
I am having an Android app in which I have implemented the Google Sign In for user identity purposes. I am having the Google idToken (jwt) via this login which I want to use with my spring boot backend as user identity (i.e. don't want to implement any login at backend side). And after the user authentication at spring boot backend side using the idToken jwt, I want to implement oauth2 auth server to get the access and refresh tokens in exchange of idToken so that I don't have to provide the idToken in every request to access the resources since in order to get the idToken from Google sign in on Android, it shows a gui flow which will be annoying for users if repeated
in order to stay connected, instead an access and refresh token combination would be good for long lived connection.

How can I authenticate a user/request against the idToken jwt in springboot?
How to use the authentication achieved in above step to implement the oauth2 auth server to get the access and refresh tokens?

I have tried for the authentication using JwtAuthenticationProvider as below but it's giving Forbidden 403 error:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    fun filterChain(http:HttpSecurity) : SecurityFilterChain {
        val decoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs").build()
        return http
            .sessionManagement { it.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS) }
            .authorizeHttpRequests { it.anyRequest().authenticated() }
            .authenticationProvider(JwtAuthenticationProvider(decoder))
            .build()
    }
}

